# Kubernetes CronJob multiple schedule times

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

I want to run one cron at different times.

Is it possible to do something like this in my YML file:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cronjob
spec:
  schedule: 
    - "*/10 00-08 * * *"
    - "*/5 09-18 * * *"
    - "*/10 19-23 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
...
```

or do I have to create separate YML files for every schedule time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is: no, you cannot create one `CronJob` YML with several crontab times schedules.

The easy solution would be to use separate [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) resource for each crontab line from your example. You can use the same image for each of your `CronJobs`.