# CronJob with Multiple Time Intervals

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

Is there a valid **schedule** for creating a **single** Kubernetes CronJob that runs a job every four hours, once a day at 7 AM, and once a week on Sunday at 7 AM?

Comment: No - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65122937/3537880